# Проблемы с текстом в php

Tags: php

я столкнулся проблемой, у меня есть переменная $name в которой стоит лимит по клоичеству символов(40 сим.), я проверял сколько символов в этой переменной и больше 40 не было, пока я не добавил к 39 символу двойную ковычку, проверив сколько символов я увидел что их там 45, хочу сказать что значение переменная $name принимает следующим образом:Пользователь вводит свой ник, и нажимает на кнопку "зарегестрироваться" данные отпровляются пост методом в файл check.php там значение которое было передано я записываю в переменную $name использовав htmlspecialchars, так вот вопрос:Как мне сделать чтобы эти кавычки были как один символ при этом не давая юзеру вводить html теги?

Comment: Сделайте проверку до `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: В большинстве случаев не надо применять htmlspecialchars перед сохранением в базу. htmlspecialchars  надо применять при выводе в html. То есть в базе лежит значение как есть, а в html выводится в htmlspecialchars, чтобы отображалось правильно и исключило [XSS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Межсайтовый_скриптинг). Вы не всегда будете выводить html, иногда значение надо вывести в json (для api или ajax-запросов) и тогда htmlspecialchars не нужен.

Comment: Лимит по количеству символов кривой.

Comment: @Егор Банин, а как же нулевые unicode символы? которые могут разрывать SQL запрос прямо на лету.

Comment: @3xcepts ты, конечно же, можешь привести пример такого запроса с таким символом?

Comment: @Ипатьев, `FEFF` `&#65279;` погугли там много чего интересного найдешь.

Comment: @3xcepts byte order mark вообще никак не влияет на SQL и прекрасно сохраняется в БД

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Почему Вам не сделать проверку на количество символов  до использования `htmlspecialchars`. Вы также можете использовать [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php). Функция "strip_tags" - убирает html теги и комментария. Также в этой функции можно передать тегов, какие не следует удалять.

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text); // Test paragraph. Other text
```

Comment: Также в этой функции можно передать тегов, какие не следует удалять и сделать огромную дыру в безопасности